# WPF: Created system tray icon but it is corralled in subwindow

Tags: wpf, system-tray, trayicon

I added a tray icon to my app, but most of the time in order to see it in Windows 8.1,
I have to click on an up arrow in the tray icon area that brings up a subwindow
that has numerous other tray icons.

How can I get my tray icon to always appear in the tray icon area?

Comment: Not really a prograamming question, so you might get more help on Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to achieve programmatically, this is an OS user preference that is controlled by the end user.

The best you can do is alert user with an explanation on how to customize the tray to always show your tray icon.

EDIT:

Apparently it might be possible to actually do this by modifying the registry... check out this blog post: [New Windows Tray / Notification Manager is here!](http://hianz.wordpress.com/2013/09/03/new-windows-tray-notification-manager-is-here/)